# extension methods are not colored any more after the last update on visual studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, extension-methods

I have just updated the visual studio to its latest version. Then I opened it and I saw that the extension methods are not colored any more with the gold color and they are not get distinguished. From now on they are colored white.

How can i revert it and be colored again ?

[image]

Comment: You could check the official documentation.
See if this works: Tools > Options. Under Environment, see Fonts and Colors.

Comment: Try switching to light mode and then back to dark mode.

Comment: @LegacyCode i have tried it before i create the post but did not work

Comment: You can't make any assumptions about who downvoted, nor should you- it's not an insult, it's simply feedback that something about your post needs to be improved. Yes it might have caused your Fake Internet Points counter to go down by one or two but does that matter? Is it worth going to war with the people who try to help you?

Comment: @CaiusJard I am sorry if i demonstrated a bad attitude. My assumption derived after his /her answer on reading the official documentation and at the same time the provided answer did not work. So, i assume that someone who says read the official documentation and the same person provides an answer that does not work without having read the official documentation, that makes me feel a bit strange.

Comment: Yes, I did. Don't intend to demoralize you on asking a questions, but they do mention such things in the documentation. 
Hopefully, this will help: Tools > Options. Go to Text Editor >  Select the language > Code style > Formatting.
If it doesn't then I would suggest checking the various options in the Options Menu :)

Comment: @noruk no one has posted any answers yet, these are just comments. Namandeep has asked if you have checked the docs and tried the options- if you have done it then edit your question to say you have, include a screenshot of what your settings look like so we can compare to ours, and I'm sure the downvote will be reversed. Like I said, it's only an indicator that something needs to be improved, it is not a negative statement about you in any personal/professional way. Always try to edit your question to include info requested in comments, do not put the info in comments or answers.

Comment: StackOverflow developers seem to have never quite grasped the psychological connotations associated with down voting and it's negativity. It comes up on meta from time to time but they never change it. You will, I'm afraid, have to learn to perceive it differently until they see sense and make it not so day/night, best/worst, good/evil etc

Comment: @Namandeep_Kaur the reason i created the post was to just earn time. I believe my question is useful because many people would not like to work without having color distinguisher.  Because  I thought it would be people who have done the update before me and they might faced the same issue. So, i thought someone would already know. However I added a new answer with the correct way to revert it as it was, in case someone faces the same issue.

Comment: That's awesome! Glad you could find it quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Finally the correct way to revert it as it was is:

*Tools - Options - Text Editor - C# - Advanced - Editor Color Scheme and change it to Visual Studio 2019*

It seems that after the visual studio update, the color scheme changed to Visual Studio 2017